# Update DNS records with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, active-directory

i would like to write a powershell script that will update the name of a list of DNS A records.

However , i also need to update the PTR records that correspond to the DNS records.
As far as i read there is no parameter that will do this for me automatically and i decided to write a separate script that will handle the Ptr records.

I am not sure what is the correct approach to update the pointer record PtrDomainName(see code below).
I managed to find info about the approach to change the IP and the TTL (both in my code) but the name is missing.

```
$records = Get-Content .\ptr_records.txt

foreach ($record in $records){
    #modify the records
    $OldObj = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName 10.in-addr.arpa -RRType Ptr | Where-Object {$_.RecordData.PtrDomainName -like $record }
    $NewObj = $OldObj.Clone()
    ###below line modifies time to live
    $NewObj.TimeToLive = [System.TimeSpan]::FromHours(2) 
    ###below line modifies ip
    $NewObj.RecordData.IPv4Address = [ipaddress]'8.8.8.8'
    ###how do i modify the record data?????
    $NewObj.RecordData= ??? 
Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -NewInputObject $NewObj -OldInputObject $OldObj -ZoneName "10.in-addr.arpa" -PassThru
    
}
```

here is also some powershell output:

in the example below dnsrecord1 will be changed to dnsrecord2

```
PS C:\Users\da.v.kolev> $test = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName 10.in-addr.arpa -RRType Ptr | Where-Object {$_.RecordData.PtrDomainName -like 'dnsrecord1.contoso.com.' }
PS C:\Users\da.v.kolev> $test

HostName                  RecordType Type       Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData
--------                  ---------- ----       ---------            ----------      ----------
1.33.22                   PTR        12         0                    01:00:00     dnsrecord1.contoso.com.


PS C:\Users\da.v.kolev> $test.RecordData

PtrDomainName                          PSComputerName
-------------                          --------------
dnsrecord1.contoso.com.


PS C:\Users\da.v.kolev> $test.RecordData.PtrDomainName
dnsrecord1.contoso.com.
PS C:\Users\da.v.kolev>
```

Comment: i think it might be something like $NewObj.RecordData.PtrDomainName = "dnsrecord2.constoso.com." , however I am not sure about this and if its the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you update a DNS A-record with a new IP.

For a PTR record, the IP-address is part of the name and it can't be updated. So, the PTR record will be obsolete and needs to be removed; then a new record needs to be created.